# Duplicate the swap function

Tags: function-construction, assignment

Because defining the function:

```
swap[x_, y_] := Module[{}, t = x; x = y; y = t; Return[]]
```

and writing:

```
swap[x, y]
{x, y}
```

I get:

```
{y, y}
```

and not `{y, x}` as I would like?

Thank you!

Comment: is `swap` meant to swap the *values* stored in `x` and `y`, or is it meant to symbolically swap the two *expressions*?

Comment: What is the point of `Module` here? What is the point of `Return`?

Comment: As to `Module`, you may want to read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8228/1871), as to `Return`, you may want to read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58089/1871).

Comment: Why the title is *duplicate* the swap function? I didn't know that Mathematica has its own swap function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Attributes[swap] = HoldAll;

swap[x_, y_] := {x, y} = {y, x};

x = 1;
y = 2;

swap[x, y];

{x, y}
```

> ```
> {2, 1}
> ```

There are two characteristics of this code worth noting.  The first is the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) [Attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html):

- [How do I treat elements in a list as variables inside a module?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3269/121)
- [When should I, and when should I not, set the HoldAll attribute on a function I define?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4126/121)
- [Pass function or formula as function parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8865/121)
- [How to modify function argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/121)

The second is the evaluation of `{x, y} = {y, x}` itself, which is related.  Let us consider how else we might implement this.  Essentially we need to store the present values of `x` and `y` before reassigning these Symbols to the opposite value.  That might be done verbosely like this:

```
x1 = x;
y1 = y;
x = y1;
y = x1;
```

This requires that two additional Symbols be introduced which is less clean than ideal.  Instead we can store the original values within the evaluation sequence itself.  First understand that `Set` (short form `=`) has the [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute.  This means that in the expression `{x, y} = {y, x}` (long form `Set[{x, y}, {y, x}]`) the second argument will be evaluated before `Set` does anything, but the first argument will be held in an unevaluated form.  Indeed we find this in the output of [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html):

```
x = 1;  y = 2;

TracePrint[{x, y} = {y, x}];

  (* other print lines omitted*)
```

> {x, y} = {2, 1}

Thanks to the fact that `Set` operates on lists this then performs the reassignment that we want.  If it did not we could still perform this action without using intermediate (temporary) variables like `x1` and `y1` by using the same kind of evaluation control.

```
(x = #2; y = #1) &[x, y]
```

Here a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is used which (by default) evaluates its arguments but holds the body of the function `(x = #2; y = #1)` unevaluated until its [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)s are filled.

Comment: @Manu You are welcome, and I am glad I can help.  This really is *not* a stupid question as it requires some specific knowledge and understanding regarding evaluation semantics in *Mathematica*.  It's actually a very nice *minimal example* of a couple of different properties.  I suspect the question will end up being of use to other newish users.

Answer (score 7):

Just a reminder for advanced users, to show the complexity of the problem :

[image]

[image]

keywords : David Wagner power programming swap byname